# Connect to Citrix with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, citrix, citrix-access-gateway

This is my first question here.

In my work, we connect to our internal network with smart cards.
Thus, when we want to connect to Citrix, we just open CheckPoint's Hammer (from all programs menu), then press ctrl+alt+delete and then type our personal password (for the smart card).

Since **we don't have username and password for Citrix**, I don't know how to connect automatically using VBA (i.e. from Excel).

I [found a code](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/53009-use-vba-to-access-published-application-in-program-neghbourhood/) that requires username and password, which I don't have (it starts well and then stucks):

```
Sub checkConnected()
    Dim cli As New WFICALib.ICAClient
    cli.SetProp "Address", "255.255.255.255"
    cli.SetProp "Username", "xxxxxxxxxx"
    cli.SetProp "Password", "xxxxxxxxxx"
    cli.SetProp "Domain", "xxxxxxx"
    cli.Startup
    cli.Launch = True
    cli.Connect
    Debug.Print cli.AUTHUsername
    Debug.Print cli.Connected
    Debug.Print cli.GetSessionCount
End Sub
```

I would love to get your Help. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you tagging both Excel VBA and Access VBA?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Are you trying to have Excel or Access connect through Citrix to an office network?  It's unclear what you're doing.  Can you provide more details.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Actually, I want to create macro that pulls data from apps in Citrix to Excel and Access that on my computer. So I need to connect the VBA to citrix apps.

Comment: If it asks for credentials you don't have, obviously nothing will help you.

Comment: I connect to Citrix in my work without this credentials, because of the smart card. So it is possible to do so, and manually I do that. I just have to figure out how to do it automatically with VBA.

Comment: IF you connect using that smart card, I don't think VBA can be a substitute of that smart card. If you have it, then maybe the method SendKeys combined with the smart card can help you

Comment: Thank you! That what I thought to do (using sendkeys), yet I have the problem of access the apps in Citrix (assume that I already connected). How do I do that?

Comment: If you have the smart card, then just access typing whatever you type. There are plenty of answers in the Internet which can teach you how to SendKeys to simulate whatever you want to simulate. Also, check Citriz Website. I'm sure there you will find about connecting Excel and Citrix

Comment: The connection is not the problem, I can do it with sendkeys (I know how to use it). The issue is to use apps in Citrix, after I connected (manually or with sendkeys).

Answer (score 1):

have you talked to your company IT/ data security team? Checkpoint Is usually there to secure corporate data, and the intention is that you cannot remove it from the internal network. Can you not use excel and access within Citrix to collect and present the data, rather than trying to pull the data off the network and onto your PC? 
Your IT team will be able to help you find the best and most secure way to do what you want.